# Communicate between tomcat instances (Distributed Architecture)

Tags: java, tomcat, distributed

We have a distributed architecture where our application runs on four Tomcat instances. I would like to know the various options available for communicating between these Tomcat instances.

The details : Say a user sends a request to stop listening to the incoming queues, this needs to be communicated with other Tomcat instances so that they stop their listeners as well. How can this communication be made across Tomcats?

Thanks,
Midhun

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are facing coordination problem.

I'd recommend you to use [Apache ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) for this kind of the problems.
Consider putting your configuration to the ZooKeeper. ZooKeeper allows you to *watch* for the changes and if configuration was changed in ZooKeeper tomcat instance will be notified and you can adjust the behavior of your application on every node.

You can use any kind of external persistent storage to solve this problem, though.

Other possible way is to implement communication between tomcat nodes by yourself but in this case you'll have a problem with managing your deployment topology: every tomcat node should know about other nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

what lies on the surface is RMI, HTTP requests. As well, IMHO, you could try to use MBeans. One more thing, you could use some non-java related things, like DBus or something, or even flat files... if all tomcats run on the same machine. Lots of options...

Answer (score 0):

We use [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.org) for this kind of scenario. They have an handy [Http Session Clustering](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.1/manual/multi_html/ch10.html)